# Can't change the size of View Element in Xcode (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I am new to iOS Dev and Xcode.

I was trying to practice Auto Layouts in Xcode.

So I was faced with a problem where I wanted to have my score label 20 points from the left side of stack view. So I embedded my label in a UIview element and was able to constraint it to 20 points from left. However, it seems like my UIview element's size has been locked and I am unable to reduce its size.

[image]

I want my view element to take same height as my score label which is like 71.5 points but it turns out that minimum height that can be reached for this UIview element is 333.5 as you can see in the image above.

So, how can I reduce its height and did I do anything wrong?

----------- **Updated: Here are the constraints** -----------

[image]

Comment: from stackview it self try to set distribution as fill proportionally, also may I know why you need all elements to be inside stackview ?

Comment: You're missing a couple constraints, and it looks like you have an erroneous constraint on your white view. Re-do your screen-shot, with all of the arrows expanded (so we can see all of the constraints).

Comment: @DonMag, thanks for the reply ... I have updated the question to include the constraints.

Comment: @MohammedGomaa, The distribution was set to fill proportionally, (I have edited the question to include another screenshot) ... Since I needed to stack all these element vertically (such as question text, true, false, progress bar), that's why I thought that stack view will be best to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the `MyView.top = top` constraint.

Your "Score:" label already has `top`, `leading` and `trailing` constraints to `MyView`, so add a `bottom = Score:.bottom` constraint. That will tell the bottom of the white `MyView` to stick to the bottom of the label.

You may also need to set the Score label's `Content Hugging` vertical priority to `Required (1000)`.

That should do it.